# dynamic html pages in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. 
I have html page(audit.html) which displays list of unique ids to right side of page. 
This is my RouteProvider for this page.There is a links on left nav bar for htmls mentioned here.

```
    .config(function( $routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
    .when( '/home', { 
        controller: 'homeController', 
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html" 
        } )
    .when('/audit',{ 
        controller: 'AuditController', 
        templateUrl: "templates/audit.html" 
        })
        .when('/submit',{ 
        controller: 'SubmitController', 
        templateUrl: "templates/submit.html" 
        })
```

I want to display data stored against unique ID when I click on any Ids listed.I want to display details on same page.
How can we do dynamic routing in Angular JS.

Comment: to pass the query string, In your case it is `id` you can map the route like this `.when('/audit/:id',{ // your code ahead `

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your config to the following (as Govind suggested):

```
.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', { 
      controller: 'homeController', 
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    })
    .when('/audit/:id',{ 
      controller: 'AuditController', 
      templateUrl: "templates/audit.html" 
    })
    .when('/submit',{ 
      controller: 'SubmitController', 
      templateUrl: "templates/submit.html" 
    });
```

Then in your controller you can do something like the following:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.auditId = $stateParams.id;
  });
```

Which will allow you to bind it to your template.

You can read more about how URL routing works [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean to say if audit id is present , I can show details of an audit ID and hide list of ids html page or vice versa.